# Kafka stream KTable changelog TTL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

Let’s say I have an `A-Event` KStream aggregated into an `A-Snapshot` KTable and a `B-Event` KStream aggregated into a `B-Snapshot` KTable. Neither `A-Snapshot` nor `B-Snapshot` conveys null values (delete events are instead aggregated as state attribute of the snapshot). At this point, we can assume we have a persisted kafka changelog topic and a rocksDB local store for both the `A-KTable` and `B-KTable` aggregations. Then, my topology would join the `A-KTable` with `B-KTable` to produce a joined `AB-KStream`. That said, my problem is with the `A-KTable` and `B-KTable` materialization lifecycles (both the changelog topic and the local rocksdb store). Let’s say `A-Event` topic and `B-Event` topic retention strategies were set to 2 weeks, is there a way to side effect the kafka internal KTable materialization topic retention policy (changelog and rocksDB) with the upstream event topic delete retention policies? Otherwise, can we configure the KTable materialization with some sort of retention policy that would manage both the changelog topic and the rockdb store lifecycle? Considering I can’t explicitly emit `A-KTable` and `B-KTable` snapshot tombstones? I am concerned that the changelog and the local store will grow indefinitely,..,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, KStream doesn't support out of the box functionality to inject the cleanup in Changelog topics based on the source topics retention policy. By default, it uses the "Compact" retention policy.

There is an open JIRA issue for the same : 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4212

One option is to inject tombstone messages but that's not nice way.
In case of windowed store, you can use "compact, delete" retention policy.